# Cannot import PyQt in Python Tools for Visual Studio 2013 and no auto-completion

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-2013, pyqt, ptvs

I am using Python Tools for Visual Studio 2013. Now I also want to use PyQt for my User Interface.

I successfully installed PyQt and used it in other IDEs (e.g. PyCharm). Now I want to import PyQt in Visual Studio 2013, but it down't work.

This code

```
from PyQt import QtGui

print('Hello World')
```

leads to the following error:

> No module named 'PyQt'

I already added `Qt.pyd`, `QtCore.pyd` and `QtGui.pyd` to the References of my Python project in Visual Studio 2013. But still, the PyQt cannot be found and is also not detected by Auto-completion.

---

**Update**

Shadow9043's advice solved the problem. However, I still got no code-completion for the PyQt classes.
I get warnings when importing (Unable to resolve "PyQt") and I don't get the list of members when using PyQt classes.

Is there anyway to get VS2013 to "know" the PyQt classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting your import statement wrong.

Using python shell with:

```
>>> from PyQt import QtGui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt import QtGui
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt'
```

To fix this you need to specify the PyQt version on the import. See below:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui  # For PyQt5
from PyQt4 import QtGui  # For PyQt4
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this when I'm back at home. Oddly, it works with `from PyQt` in PyCharm. Also, VS doesn't give any import suggestions (auto-complete) for the PyQt libs. Not for `PyQt4` either.

Comment: When I type a PyQt class and enter `.` I get a tooltip saying "The completion DB needs to be refreshed.". So I open the Python Environments window and wait for the DB to be refreshed. But it never does. The loading bar of "Refreshing DB" loads until about 60% and then stops.

Comment: Do you have some information on my last comment? It seems to be stuck at "Analyzing standard library".